# Windows 10 not getting gpo deployed printers

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, network-printer, windows-10

In a small network (5 clients, more "users"), I have two Windows Server 2008 R2 acting as Active Directory DC and file and print servers, where I did setup several GPO, and printer deployment.

This was acting perfectly with Windows 7 and 8.1 clients, but since I did the Windows 10 free upgrade, I have to add the printers manually on each user's session, the automatique printer deployment does not work anymore.

Is there any change in Windows 10 asking for some GPO change to keep it working?

I know the manual mode is not such a hassle on a 5 clients network, but I use to provide support at night where users need to work on business day, and they really aren't used to IT, even addind a network printer is complicated to them, and they sometimes have to log on another computer, where the session is new and the printer is missing ...

Comment: Should work fine with Windows 10. I have no problems in my environment with clients of Windows 7/8/10. Did you configure the printers in the computer or user configuration? Have you checked the event log (eventvwr.exe)? Have you checked if the policy gets applied (gpresult.exe)?

Comment: Does the server have the necessary drivers to deploy to Windows 10 clients?

Comment: You need to spend some time looking at your event logs. If GPO printer deployments are failing, the logs will tell you why, or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: After the latest patches, you can't even add them manually and. Issue occurs at least between 2021R2 and updated 10s.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, couldn't deploy a printer via GPO to Windows 10 clients.  The fix was to download and add the most up-to-date printer driver that works with Windows 10 to the print server, then update the driver in the printer instance.

Answer (score 0):

win 10 upgrades were getting the printers, but for some reason fresh win 10 were not. in the GPO manager; I clicked enforce (even though I'm not blocking) and did a gpupdate /force. the printers showed up.